# overflow-x: hidden doesn't work, instead adds padding on the right when scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using position: fixed for a modal box (position: fixed for the outer container that shows a dark background and position: absolute for the modal box) as mentioned in the css below. I have added overflow-y: auto and overflow-x: hidden to the modal box, but when the scroll starts i.e. when content overflows, an extra padding appears on the right bottom corner (as seen in the gif below). I want to avoid this padding. How do I go about?

Thanks.

Inline CSS for Modal Box:

```
background:'#ccc',
zIndex:100,
padding:"20px",
borderRadius:"3px",
border:"1px solid #eee",
boxShadow: "0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
transition: "0.3s",
paddingTop:"55px",
top : '50%',
left : '50%',
right : 'auto',
bottom : 'auto',
maxHeight : '85%',
marginTop: "35px", 
overflowY : "auto",
overflowX: "hidden",
width : "60%",
verticalAlign: "top",
minHeight : "70%",
transform : 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
position:"absolute"
```

Inline CSS for the outer dark background

```
position : 'fixed',
{top : 0,
left : 0,
right : 0,
bottom : 0,
zIndex: 19,
background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
```

[As seen in the image, no padding is present initially. But when the text overflows, padding is added in the form of the white square box in the bottom right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0IIf.gif)

Edit:

Sorry for all the mistakes in the post. I am including a js fiddle of the question https://jsfiddle.net/kbsfph91. Also, I figured out the exact problem. The problem is that I am using a contentEditable div in my modal box, and when the content overflows, the padding occurs because scrollbars are supposed to appear, but they don't. So the empty space that comes up is the invisible scrollbar (scrolling works though). So my question should be how do I make the scrollbar visible?

Comment: We need to see a demo code snippet to investigate this with any certainty.

Comment: You should edit your question to format the code neater. Maybe even make a runable snippet out of it. But as to your question: `Overflow-Y: auto` will add a scrollbar when it deems fit. THAT is your padding. `Overflow-X: hidden` does not hide such scrollbars. (or, only when on the parent element)

Comment: Please provide a snippet/demo that makes the problem **reproducable**. As is, it's quite hard to see/analyze the problem here.

Comment: This is a result of adjustments being made to account for the spacing required for the scroll panes to appear. Why these scroll panes do not appear correctly I can only speculate, but consider verifying that there are no browser specific styles being declared to customise the scroll bars (keep an eye out for style rules with vendor prefixes, like `-webkit-`). One method you could explore to negate this spacing adjustment is to use the  `overlay` value for your `overflow` property rules, this will *overlay* the scroll pane above the content, preserving inner-spacing of the box-model.

Comment: Sorry for all the mistakes in the post. I am including a js fiddle of the question https://jsfiddle.net/kbsfph91/. Also, I figured out the exact problem. The problem is that I am using a contentEditable div in my modal box, and when the content overflows, the padding occurs because scrollbars are supposed to appear, but they don't. So the empty space that comes up is the invisible scrollbar (scrolling works though). So **how do I make the scrollbar visible** should be my question.

Comment: The scrollbar remains visible in the JSFiddle example as well. See the updated JSFiddle which demonstrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/kbsfph91/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This css code solved my problem - by hiding scrollbar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 0px;
  }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-radius: 4px;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 }
```